# Recovering the Weinstein Splitting Theorem for Poisson manifolds using the Local Splitting theorem for Lie algebroids

Tags: poisson-geometry, lie-algebroids

How can I recover the Weinstein Splitting Theorem for Poisson manifolds using the Local Splitting theorem for Lie algebroids? I am using the formulation of the theorem given in https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0007132.pdf. On Page 13, Fernades gives the following [hint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Mgam.png)

I made some fruitless attempts =(